Tagdiv Composer crashes when adding woocommerce shortcode
I am use wordpress and using the newpaper theme. I added the woocommerce shortcode ([products limit=”4″ columns=”4″ orderby=”id” order=”DESC” visibility=”visible”]) and got this error. If I save and f5, the page cannot be edited anymore. Can someone help me?



It sounds like there might be a conflict between the WooCommerce shortcode and your theme.

Once check theme Theme Compatibility and plugins compatibility.
Try to disable all plugin once and one by one activate all to identify.

